# Receive TouchesBegan of UITableViewCell in UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, touchesbegan

How can I receive TouchesBegan from a UITableViewCell in a UITableViewController so I can know when the user touches some cell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you touch the a cell, it becomes highlighted; try overriding `setHighlighted:` in a subclass of `UITableViewCell` to adjust your appearance when it changes to YES (user touching) or NO (user lifted off).

(Overriding `touchesBegan:withEvent:` will also work, but it's easier to use `setHighlighted:` in order to capture when you're not longer touching; otherwise you need to override `touchesEnded:withEvent:` and `touchesCancelled:withEvent:`).

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for an event that is triggered when a user taps a cell, but before it is officially selected, there is the `UITableViewDelegate` method:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

From the documentation:

> This method is not called until users touch a row and then lift their
>   finger; the row isn't selected until then, although it is
>   highlighted on touch-down. You can use
>   UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone to disable the appearance of the
>   cell highlight on touch-down. This method isn’t called when the table
>   view is in editing mode (that is, the editing property of the table
>   view is set to YES) unless the table view allows selection during
>   editing (that is, the allowsSelectionDuringEditing property of the
>   table view is set to YES).

**EDIT**

In order to achieve the behavior you're seeking, I believe you need to subclass `UITableViewCell` and implement the method

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

You can find more about the event handling in the [`UIResponder` class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIResponder), which all UIViews subclass from.

Comment: That's what I want, but not exactly. When you place your finger over a regular cell, it becomes selected (blue). In the custom cell I'm using, this selection happens under the cell itself, so I disabled it setting the style to "none". I want to call a method exactly when the user touches the cell. This method you suggested is only triggered after the user selects the cell, but not when he just places his finger over it.

Comment: @Sync  I suspected that that was what you want, I made an edit to my answer that should hopefully assist you